# Joining 2 PostgreSQL Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

OK, this sounds like a very basic question with an obviously basic solution. I'm not a great user of SQL but I have an issue joining two tables. Probably best that I show you what I'm trying to join together:

Table 1, **students_info**:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| NAME        ID         DEPARTMENT        N |
+--------------------------------------------+
| Joe Blogs   234-2      Maths             2 |
| Jane Doe    342-6      Physics           4 |
| John Smith  356-1      Chemistry         7 |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Table 2, **students_grades**:

```
+--------------------------------+
| SUBJECT         GRADE     N   |
+--------------------------------+
| Chemistry       B         NULL |
| Physics         A         NULL |
| Maths           A         NULL |
| Engineering     B         NULL |
| NULL            NULL      2    |
+--------------------------------+
```

Both tables contain a column called N. The table **students_info** comes with this already, however I added a column N to the **students_grades** table with the hope that I could join the 2 tables via this column.

Now, I'm interested in *Joe Blogs* from **students_info** hence the reason I placed the 2 in the N column of table **students_grades**. I was therefore hoping to grab all information about *Joe Blogs* and output. The output table would then display his name, ID, department and subjects with grades.

Does anyone know how I might go about doing this? Someone the other day suggested using a *Foreign Key*..?

Note: Essentially, each student (or row) from **students_info** has its own table, **students_grades**.

What I'm looking for is something which would look like (in my head):

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| NAME        ID       DEPARTMENT       SUBJECT        GRADE     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Joe Blogs   234-2    Maths            Chemistry      B         |
|                                       Physics        A         |
|                                       Maths          A         |
|                                       Engineering    B         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Cheers

Comment: ID from students_info needs to be in students_grades as a foreign key.

Comment: N=2 in students_grades table has NULL in all other columns. So what is your expectation for Joe Blogs in column Subject and Grade?

Comment: *Essentially, each student (or row) from students_info has its own table, students_grades* you should reconsider this design.

Comment: Or, populate N in the second table with numbers corresponding to the students that pertain to each record.

Comment: Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. This shows no effort to inform yourself. What parts are you able to do? What did your textbook or the documentation say about anything relevant? PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. PS A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To associate the information in the grades table with your student Joe, the table should look like this:

```
+-------------------------------+
| SUBJECT         GRADE     N   |
+-------------------------------+
| Chemistry       B         2   |
| Physics         A         2   |
| Maths           A         2   |
| Engineering     B         2   |
+-------------------------------+
```

You could add more rows for the other students, e.g. for assigning Jane an A in Chemistry and John a C in Maths:

```
| Chemistry       A         4   |
| Maths           C         7   |
```

To join these, you'd use

```
SELECT * FROM students_info JOIN students_grades USING (N)
```

The `N` column should be declared as unique in the `students_info` table, and the `students_grades.N` column should be a foreign key referencing the former. Alternatively, make it reference the `ID` column and don't introduce an extra artificial key in `students_info`.

Answer (score 0):

If I guess correct, you are looking for a script as below. But as per your sample data, you will basically get NULL in both Subject and Grade field for Joe Blogs as row contain 2 in N column in table students_grades basically has no data in other columns.

```
SELECT
A.NAME,
A.ID,
A.DEPARTMENT,
B.SUBJECT,
B.GRADE
FROM students_info A
INNER JOIN students_grads B
ON A.N = B.N
```

Comment: Is your give sample data are real?

Comment: I'm not the OP.

Comment: @mkRabbani. Well essentially real. I'm basically trying to learn

Comment: From your data and explained relation between tables, I can only pick NULL for you in columns Subject and Grade :)